How to implement a list of bitset<n> that takes different lengths, and iterates over the list
I wrote a function that processes a bitset<N>:
template<size_t N>
bool do_sth_with_bitset(std::bitset<N> &target) {
  ...
}

I have multi std::bitset<N>, with different N. How can I iterate over them and use my function to process it?

What do you mean by "multi bitset"?  A single container contains one type of object.

For example, I have bitse<1>, bitse<2>, bitse<3>.... ..etc. Can I iterate through them?

You have them in what?  You can't have them in a vector or a list, because those have to be homogeneous, and if they aren't in a container (which they can't be), then they can't be iterated.  So, I guess the answer is "no".

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Do you need to store the objects in a container or they have already been constructed? Do you need to iterate over them or is it sufficient to pass a variadic number of arguments? For example, std::bitset<N>& ....
